# How to make <option>s have a width only covering their content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, select

I know the dropdown section is rendered by the browser, but I posted this on the CSS section and they said it can be done through JS.

What I need is that every option on the dropdown list, including the selected one at top, to have a width only covering content. Right now it creates a box with a width of the longest option.

Comment: What do you mean with 'Only covering content'?

Comment: like an inline-block, having the width of its content rather than a fixed # or %

Comment: I think this is simply not possible, as every browser renders a `select` element in a different way. CSS has very little influence on `select` elements.

Comment: Isn't it possible through js or a different library or something?

Comment: You can create your custom select dropdown through JS though.

Comment: I just posted an answer that will do that, the logic behind it is to copy the text to a temporary span and then get the width of that span.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        var optWidth = $("#temp").html($("select").find(":selected").text()).width();
        $(this).width(optWidth);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4tzRy/

Comment: this almost works; what I need is to have every option have the minimum length when the dropdown's active, not just the option selected.